# Redirect form to different URL based on select option element

Tags: javascript, select, onclick

new to JavaScript seeking some help.  I have a form with a select drop down with 5 options.
     
             Option1
             Option2
             option3
             Option4
             Option5'

I need to have the form to redirect to another url if any of the options are selected apart from Option 1 which should be the default one on page load.

Thank you in advance

I only used the following

```
<form action="" id="main" name="main" method="get" onChange="top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">

<select id="Region" name="Region" tabindex="7">
   <option value="/url">Option1</option>
   <option value="/url">Option2</option>
   <option value="/url">Option3</option>
   <option value="/url>Option4</option>
   <option value="" selected="selected">Option5</option>'
</select>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just use a `onchnage Event` for select box.

```
<select id="selectbox" name="" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
    <option value="https://www.yahoo.com/" selected>Option1</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.co.in/">Option2</option>
    <option value="https://www.gmail.com/">Option3</option>

</select>
```

And if selected option to be loaded at the page load then add some javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        location.href=document.getElementById("selectbox").value;
    }       
</script>
```

for jQuery: Remove the onchange event from `<select>` tag

```
jQuery(function () {
    // remove the below comment in case you need chnage on document ready
    // location.href=jQuery("#selectbox").val(); 
    jQuery("#selectbox").change(function () {
        location.href = jQuery(this).val();
    })
})
```

Comment: if I wanted to achieve the same result using only jQuery?

Comment: Why one is onLoad and another with jQuery is onChange? The first one works not as aspected - I can not choose the value, I'm redirected before this ;)

Comment: @KrishnaKumar, I want the dropdown is selected after redirecting to url, is that can be done?

Answer (score 16):

you can use this simple way

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
                <option value="/finished">Finished</option>
                <option value="/break">Break</option>
                <option value="/issue">Issues</option>
                <option value="/downtime">Downtime</option>
</select>
```

will redirect to route url you can direct to .html page or direct to some link just change `value` in option.

Answer (score 0):

This can be archived by adding code on the onchange event of the select control.

For Example:

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="http://gmail.com">Gmail</option>
    <option value="http://youtube.com">Youtube</option>
</select>
```