# Navigate to URL if specific <option> value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hi have been looking around how to do something like this with jquery or JavaScript but can't seem to find it.

So let's say I have a form with a select field in it.

Ex:

```
<select id="Country">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    Etc.....
</select>
```

All I want is when user selects the option with value="Canada"
To have them redirected to a different URL. Note: I can't modify the  I need to be able to have jquery/javascript see value Canada was selected and send them to a different URL as soon as they make that selection.

Comment: What have you tried so far... I am sure there are many solutions already for such problem..

Comment: @Kudzai you are wrong..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150363/onchange-open-url-via-select-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388954/redirect-form-to-different-url-based-on-select-option-element might help.. there is some small changes you need to add into the code ... take that as a homework.

Comment: Do you have to generate the URL as well? I noticed that you can't change the HTML, and that there is no URL stored with each option, so if I select Canada do you have to generate a URL such as /countries/Canada ?

Comment: No all I need is to send them to a url that can be specified in the javascript only if they select Canada.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger event on Change like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#Country').on('change', function(){
        window.location.href = this.value; //USA, Canada
    }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Country").change(function(){
window.location.href=$('option :selected').value;
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Country">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    Etc.....
</select>
```

Comment: This worked: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $(document).on("change", "#Country", function(){
        
        if ($(this).val() === 'Canada'){
            window.location.replace('url.html');
        }
  
   });
   
});
</script>