# How to use redirection links for specific option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I want to redirect user to another page ("abc.html") on clicking on INR option of the select list and on clicking on other option it should not redirect to any page.
PS : I can't remove or change value attribute of other option.Any help will be really appreciated.

```html
<select>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
  <option value="INR">INR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you try something, it is fairly easy?

Comment: I am just a beginner at JS.I have tried onchange function but it didn't work.Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect form to different URL based on select option element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388954/redirect-form-to-different-url-based-on-select-option-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `change` event in jquery and check the value selected and do whatever you want like this

```js
$('select').change(function(){
if($(this).val() == 'INR'){
console.log("abc.html");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
  <option value="INR">INR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @rahul Glad, I helped. Please accept the answer for the future reference to other.